# Need help initializing 4-dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have this

```
        buttons[0].setBounds(12, 161, 96, 25);  // Numerical 0
        buttons[1].setBounds(12, 50, 42, 25);   // Numerical 1
        buttons[2].setBounds(66, 50, 42, 25);   // Numerical 2
        buttons[3].setBounds(120, 50, 42, 25);  // Numerical 3
        buttons[4].setBounds(12, 87, 42, 25);   // Numerical 4
        buttons[5].setBounds(66, 87, 42, 25);   // Numerical 5
        buttons[6].setBounds(120, 87, 42, 25);  // Numerical 6
        buttons[7].setBounds(12, 124, 42, 25);  // Numerical 7
        buttons[8].setBounds(66, 124, 42, 25);  // Numerical 8
        buttons[9].setBounds(120, 124, 42, 25); // Numerical 9
        buttons[10].setBounds(174, 124, 50, 62);// Equals button (=)
        buttons[11].setBounds(174, 50, 110, 25);// DEL Button (DEL)
        buttons[12].setBounds(120, 161, 42, 25);// DOT Button  (.)
        buttons[13].setBounds(174, 87, 50, 25); // MINUS Button(-)
        buttons[14].setBounds(234, 87, 50, 25); // PLUS Button (+)
        buttons[15].setBounds(236, 124, 50, 25);// PUTA Button (*)
        buttons[16].setBounds(236, 161, 50, 25);// DJEL Button (/)
```

And i want to optimize it. This is how i managed adding of items using an array and for-loop for something other.

```
JButton [] buttons = new JButton [17];
        String [] btnCommands = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","=","DEL",".","-","+","*","/"};

        for (int i = 0;i < btnCommands.length;i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton(btnCommands[i]);
        }
```

How would i go about doing an 4 dimensional array for the setBounds?

```
int [][][][] bounds = {{{{}}}};
```

How to initialize and use it?

Comment: 1: You do not need a 4-dimensional array for this; just a 2-dimensional array should suffice. 2: Save yourself the trouble of trying to create an array to store such values and use a layout manager instead.

Comment: I don't think you need a 4 dimensional array. You probably need a two dimensional array we're the second dimension have 4 entries in it, one for each bound.

Comment: I dont think 4-dimensional array means what you think it means.

Comment: Where you'd [*hopefully not*] use a 4D array. Say you split America into regions numbered from 0-n, and in these regions you numbered states 0-m, and those states then had counties also numbered 0-o which had some data you cared about indexed 0-p. You could do arr[region][state][county][dataIndex]. That's not what you're trying to do for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a 4 dimensional array. You probably need a two dimensional array we're the second dimension have 4 entries in it, one for each bound.

So you would have :

```
int [][] bounds = {{12, 161, 96, 25}, {12, 50, 42, 25}, ... }
```

And you would use it like :

```
buttons[0].setBounds(bounds[0][0], bounds[0][1], bounds[0][2], bounds[0][3]);
```

In your loop just replace the first dimension with `i` and keep the access of the others dimensions as is.

Comment: That did it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `JButton.setBounds(Rectangle)` method instead and have an array of `Rectangles`.

```
String[] btnCommands = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","=","DEL",".","-","+","*","/"};
Rectangle[] bounds = {
    new Rectangle(12, 161, 96, 25),  // Numerical 0
    new Rectangle(12, 50, 42, 25),   // Numerical 1
    new Rectangle(66, 50, 42, 25),   // Numerical 2
    new Rectangle(120, 50, 42, 25),  // Numerical 3
    new Rectangle(12, 87, 42, 25),   // Numerical 4
    new Rectangle(66, 87, 42, 25),   // Numerical 5
    new Rectangle(120, 87, 42, 25),  // Numerical 6
    new Rectangle(12, 124, 42, 25),  // Numerical 7
    new Rectangle(66, 124, 42, 25),  // Numerical 8
    new Rectangle(120, 124, 42, 25), // Numerical 9
    new Rectangle(174, 124, 50, 62),// Equals button (=)
    new Rectangle(174, 50, 110, 25),// DEL Button (DEL)
    new Rectangle(120, 161, 42, 25),// DOT Button  (.)
    new Rectangle(174, 87, 50, 25), // MINUS Button(-)
    new Rectangle(234, 87, 50, 25), // PLUS Button (+)
    new Rectangle(236, 124, 50, 25),// PUTA Button (*)
    new Rectangle(236, 161, 50, 25),// DJEL Button (/)
};

JButton[] buttons = new JButton[17];
for (int i = 0;i < btnCommands.length;i++) {
    JButton b = new JButton(btnCommands[i]);
    b.setBounds(bounds[i]);
    buttons[i] = b;
}
```